# build yaml-cpp lib with -m32 (32-bit) - on linux /w gcc or llvm

Tags: cmake, yaml-cpp

subject pretty much says it all:

- I downloaded yaml-cpp version 0.6.3.
- I need to compile on linux x86_64, target linux x86_32 (build on 64 bit, use result on 32-bit)
- I have been trying to add a new "YAML_BUILD_32BIT" option - similar to the existing YAML_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS option.

When I detect YAML_BUILD_32BIT is set:  I try to add "-m32" to a bunch of cmake variables.
My problem is that this list of variables seems endless or not well defined.

- "yaml_cxx_flags" are passed to the compile and link steps for the yaml-cpp library code...but not to build the google 'mock' code.  Similarly, I found other variables that I can also set, so that google-mock is compiled with -m32 as well...but then the yaml-cpp mock tests do not see the flag...and so on and so on.

I think I am missing something very fundamental.  I expect that there will be a single variable I need to update...maybe 2 or 3.  I don't expect to keep finding more and more.

--

Adding more specifics:

To CMakeLists.txt:

- added line (immediately after the similar line which creates the YAML_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS flag)

```
option(YAML_BUILD_32BIT "Build with '-m32'" OFF)
```

- then a bit later (immediately after the YAML_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS if/else):

```
   if(YAML_BUILD_32BIT)
     # seem to need this one for the shared lib link of yaml-cpp lib
     #  CXX_FLAGS passed to both compile and link
     set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -m32")
     # seem to need this one, to get flag passed to gmock build
     set(FLAG_TESTED "${FLAG_TESTED} -m32")
     # this one passed to compile and link of testcase
     set(yaml_cxx_flags "${yaml_cxx_flags} -m32")
   endif()
```

- and made "FLAG_TESTED" addive, on immediately following line:

```
    set(FLAG_TESTED "-Wextra -Wshadow -Weffc++ -pedantic -pedantic-errors ${FLAG_TESTED}")
```

Given the above, then configuring with:

```
  # using cmake/3.19.3
  cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DYAML_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DYAML_BUILD_32BIT=ON"
```

... and then building with 'make VERBOSE=1', I see that 'gmock-all.cc.o'  did not receive the -m32 flag. (gmock-all.cc.o is only the first such file in my log..there are others.)
If I remove other of the lines in my CMakeLists.txt which attempted to add flags - then other compile commands or other link commands don't see -m32 and will fail.

As I said:  I think there is something fundamental that I have misunderstood.  I suspect that it is much easier to configure a 32-bit build than I am making it.

Comment: Have you checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805874/the-proper-way-of-forcing-a-32-bit-compile-using-cmake/28047073) about compiling 32bit binaries in the 64bit environment? None of its answers suggest to set "a bunch of cmake varaibles".

Comment: we have a lot of code that we build and test in 32-bit mode (as well as 64-bit mode)...so yes (or no?)
My specific problem is how to set up the yaml-cpp configuration so that _all_ of the objects (both code, test infrastructure, and testcases) compile with -m32, and all the shared libraries and executables link with -m32.

Comment: The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28047073/3440745) to the referenced question is a **toolchain** file, which is created outside of any CMake project. Have you tried that approach? Please, show (add to the question post) what **exactly** have you tried.

Comment: Just tested: Adding line `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -m32")` immediately after the line `project(YAML_CPP VERSION 0.6.3 LANGUAGES CXX)` adds `-m32` to every compilation, even for `gmock-all.cc.o`. BTW, passing `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-m32` to `cmake` works even without modification of the project.

Comment: Thank you for your help..and your patience.Your CMakeLists.txt file seems to be different than mine - and to have different behavior.  I downloaded the tarball found on the yaml-cpp-0.6.3 release tag page.  That version's 'project' entry looks like:  "project(YAML_CPP VERSION 0.6.3)" - which seems to be different than the line you see.  I reverted all my changes and then tried to configure using 'cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DYAML_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-m32" - but see the same issue: at least files gtest-all.cpp.o and gmock-all.cc.o did not see the -m32 flag - so the build fails

Answer (score 1):

With some help from a coworker, I ended up doing the following:

- top-level CMakeLists.txt file (near line 28, immediately following definition of YAML_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS variable):

```
  option(YAML_BUILD_32BIT "Build with '-m32'" OFF)

  if(YAML_BUILD_32BIT)
     add_compile_options(-m32)
     add_link_options(-m32)
  endif()
```

- in .../test/CMakeLists.txt (near line 10):

```
  if(YAML_BUILD_32BIT)
    set(GTEST_EXTRA_FLAGS "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-m32")
  endif()
```

- then add new flag to "ExternalProject_Add(..." call (near line .../test/CMakeLists.txt:22):

```
ExternalProject_Add(
        googletest_project
        SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gtest-1.8.0"
        INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/prefix"
        CMAKE_ARGS
                -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>
                -DBUILD_GMOCK=ON
                -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON
                ${GTEST_EXTRA_FLAGS}  # <- this line added
)
```

The above has the effect of passing the extra "-m32" flag the embedded gmocktest project.

Given the above changes, the cmake command line above generates something that will build successfully (at least on RHEL-7, with gcc/5.2.0)

Hope this can help somebody else.

Henry